# How to improve my mysql query execution performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, query-performance

I have a main table named prog as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `prog` (
 `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `prog_insert_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `prog_edit_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `prog_name` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `prog_desc` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`prog_id`),
 KEY `prog_insert_date` (`prog_sabt_date`),
 KEY `prog_edit_date` (`prog_edit_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO prog VALUES
(1,'1395-01-01 11:00','1395-01-01 12:00','prog A', 'prog A description'),
(2,'1395-01-02 11:00','1395-01-02 12:00','prog B', 'prog B description'),
(3,'1395-01-03 11:00','1395-01-03 12:00','prog C', 'prog C description');
```

Because of I need using Jalali calendar in my app I decided to use varchar(16) for date columns and save them in this format : `'1395-07-20 12:43'`.

I also have three alike tables which contains several rows corresponding to each `prog_id`. They are credit, fund and pay as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `credit` (
 `credit_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `credit_insert_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `credit_edit_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `credit_prog` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `credit_amount` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `credit_desc` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`credit_id`),
 KEY `credit_prog` (`credit_prog`),
 KEY `credit_insert_date` (`credit_insert_date`),
 KEY `credit_edit_date` (`credit_edit_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO credit VALUES
(1,'1395-02-01 11:00','1395-02-01 12:00',1, 100000, 'sample description'),
(2,'1395-02-02 11:00','1395-02-02 12:00',1, 200000, 'sample description'),
(3,'1395-02-03 11:00','1395-02-03 12:00',2, 300000, 'sample description'),
(4,'1395-02-04 11:00','1395-02-04 12:00',2, 400000, 'sample description'),
(5,'1395-02-05 11:00','1395-02-05 12:00',3, 500000, 'sample description'),
(6,'1395-02-06 11:00','1395-02-06 12:00',3, 600000, 'sample description');

CREATE TABLE `fund` (
 `fund_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fund_insert_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `fund_edit_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `fund_prog` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fund_amount` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `fund_desc` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`fund_id`),
 KEY `fund_prog` (`fund_prog`),
 KEY `fund_insert_date` (`fund_insert_date`),
 KEY `fund_edit_date` (`fund_edit_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO fund VALUES
(1,'1395-03-01 11:00','1395-03-01 12:00',1, 10000, 'sample description'),
(2,'1395-03-02 11:00','1395-03-02 12:00',1, 20000, 'sample description'),
(3,'1395-03-03 11:00','1395-03-03 12:00',2, 30000, 'sample description'),
(4,'1395-03-04 11:00','1395-03-04 12:00',2, 40000, 'sample description'),
(5,'1395-03-05 11:00','1395-03-05 12:00',3, 50000, 'sample description'),
(6,'1395-03-06 11:00','1395-03-06 12:00',3, 60000, 'sample description');

CREATE TABLE `pay` (
 `pay_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pay_insert_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `pay_edit_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `pay_prog` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `pay_amount` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `pay_desc` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pay_id`),
 KEY `pay_prog` (`pay_prog`),
 KEY `pay_insert_date` (`pay_insert_date`),
 KEY `pay_edit_date` (`pay_edit_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO pay VALUES
(1,'1395-04-01 11:00','1395-04-01 12:00',1, 1000, 'sample description'),
(2,'1395-04-02 11:00','1395-04-02 12:00',1, 2000, 'sample description'),
(3,'1395-04-03 11:00','1395-04-03 12:00',2, 3000, 'sample description'),
(4,'1395-04-04 11:00','1395-04-04 12:00',2, 4000, 'sample description'),
(5,'1395-04-05 11:00','1395-04-05 12:00',3, 5000, 'sample description'),
(6,'1395-04-06 11:00','1395-04-06 12:00',3, 6000, 'sample description');
```

Now I want to have each prog row with corresponding sum of credit, fund and pay and also last edit date which should be constructed from all the tables. My query is:

```
SELECT
  prog_id,
  GREATEST(IFNULL(credit_edit_date,''),IFNULL(fund_edit_date,''),IFNULL(pay_edit_date,'')) last_edit_date,
  prog_name,
  credit_amount,
  fund_amount,
  pay_amount,
  prog_desc
FROM prog
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
        credit_prog,
        sum(credit_amount) as credit_amount,
        max(credit_edit_date) as credit_edit_date
    FROM credit GROUP BY credit_prog
) as credit ON credit_prog=prog_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
        fund_prog,
        sum(fund_amount) as fund_amount,
        max(fund_edit_date) as fund_edit_date
    FROM fund GROUP BY fund_prog
) as fund ON fund_prog=prog_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
        pay_prog,
        sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount,
        max(pay_edit_date) as pay_edit_date
    FROM pay GROUP BY pay_prog
) as pay ON pay_prog=prog_id
ORDER BY last_edit_date DESC
```

I get the true result, but in real cases with several rows in tables it takes too long to respond. I think that the main problem is the `last_edit_date` column and because that MYSQL optimizer cannot consider index on these date fields in subqueries.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/781c7/3)

Any idea to improve the execution time?

Comment: Might be worth looking at this? https://github.com/zoghal/Presian-Date-for-MySQL

Comment: Do you have at least 5.6?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Why `ORDER BY (SELECT last_edit_date) DESC` and not just `ORDER BY last_edit_date DESC` ?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080119/how-to-improve-my-mysql-query-execution-performance

Answer (score 1):

The derived tables would run somewhat faster if you replaced (in the `fund` case)

```
KEY `fund_prog` (`fund_prog`)
```

with

```
INDEX(fund_prog, fund_amount, fund_edit_date)
```

The construct

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

was very poorly optimized before 5.6.

Thanks for explaining the dates; using `VARCHAR` that way is almost as good as the `DATE` datatype.

Change

```
ORDER BY (SELECT last_edit_date) DESC
```

to simply

```
ORDER BY last_edit_date DESC
```

I don't know how much it will help, but it might be significant.  You will probably see a difference in the `EXPLAIN`.